# Visualizing a 2-torus on a planar shape using periodic boundary conditions

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-topology

A torus can be represented by a square with periodic boundary conditions, which makes it easy to draw embeddings of graphs on the torus using a piece of paper. Is there a similar mapping of the 2-torus (or n-torus) to a planar shape that can be used to visualize embeddings on the 2-torus in a format that is simple to draw on a sheet of paper? Does an octagon with periodic boundary conditions do the trick?

Comment: If by $n$-torus you mean a compact orientable genus $n$ torus, then for $n\ge1$ it can be represented as a $4n$-gon with suitable edge identifications. Whether that makes it "simple" to draw and to visualise embedded graphs is then a matter of opinion....

Comment: I guess easy to draw, still not easy to visualize